# XOR of all bits of $f(x)$ a hard-core bit

Tags: one-way-function, hard-core-predicate

Why consider a random $r$ in building a hardcore predicate in Goldreich Levin theorem? Why not consider just the XOR of all bits of the input?

Comment: Let $f : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$ be a one-way function. Consider the function $g : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^{n+1}$ defined as $g(x) = g(x_1\ldots x_n) := f(x)\Vert \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} x_i$. Is $g$ one-way? Is the xor of all input bits a hardcore predicate for $g$?

Comment: it isnt since it is part of the output. But then why cant the same be done with <x,r>. If you include that in the output that will be not be hard-core too right? Also isn't XOR the special case when r is all 1s?

Comment: Remember that GL define a *specific* OWF, for which the inner product  is hard-core.

Comment: $r$ is part of the *input* you can't *set* it to anything, it's chosen uniformly at random. But crucially it's not part of the input of the *underlying* function, so that function cannot do anything funny.

Comment: Let me try to understand here: XOR of bits is not a hardcore bit for any OWF because we can construct one where XOR is part of the output. XOR can be a hardcore of the underlying function $f$, it happens if $r= 11...1$ (all 1s) is a randomly chosen choice for the input of the GL transformation of $f$, i.e. $g$.